# Power Automate Question - Extracting Excel files from Folder then deleing folder - Automated Cloud Flow

Tags: power-automate

I want the trigger to be when folder1 is placed into folder2, which is on OneDrive. I want the automation to go into folder1, extract all excel files from folder 1, place them into folder3, and delete folder1. I am caught up on the first part of this flow. I set the trigger to "when a file is created" under OneDrive for business. But I don't really know what to do about the action.

I've tried to use the "Find Files In Folder" action for OneDrive, but it wants a search query. I can't really find good documentation on how this action functions. I'm relatively new to Power Automate and trying to figure out how to use it for our business needs. Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thanks so much.